# Pandas info for 100+ features

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataset in my disposal which consists of around 500 columns which I need to explore and keep only relevant columns. Pandas `info(verbose = True)` method does not even display this number properly. I also used missingno library to visualise nulls. However, it uses a lot of RAM. What to use instead of matplotlib here?

How do you approach datasets with a lot of features (more than 100)? Any useful workflow to eliminate useless features? How to use info() or any alternative?

Yeah, also used expand options to view everything. Question here is how to set it locally?

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

UPDATE: 
Methods or solutions to explore initial raw data are of interest.  For instance one cell script which summarises numerical features as distributions, categorical as counts and possibly something else. This can be written by myself, however, maybe there is a library or just your function which does so?

Comment: I'd recommend pairplotting subsets, and maybe `describe` method. But they're for very shallow and for a quick look. You can consider training whole dataset with regulization that may help reducing the effect of irrelevant features.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue of useless features, you could easily estimate some metrics associated with feature effectiveness and filter it out using some threshold. Check out the [sklearn feature selection docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).

Of course before doing that you'll have to make sure features are numeric and their representation is fit for the tests of your choice. To do that I suggest you check out sklearn [pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) (optional) and [preprocessing docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

Before estimating feature usefulness, make sure you cover missing data handling, encoding categorical variables and feature scaling.

Comment: Yeh, i know about these in scikit. Thanks for reminding! Maybe will give it a go, however, this is more about preparation for ML stage. I am asking really about the first steps in exploring the dataset. So this is an EDA part and not cleaning&prep.

Comment: I get your point. In addition to pandas info, you can check out [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use XGBoost's feature_importance attribute. Though, you first need to train your data using XGB & then using feature_importance, consider only important features (by setting a threshold of your choice)
2. Dimension reduction can come handy using PCA or some other algorithm.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about general understanding of the data. .info() for instance does not render properly on the screen with this number. .describe() may be handy however for numerical features only.